# $locationprovider.html5mode(true) is not working on refresh its very critical for my project

Tags: php, angularjs, mod-rewrite

The usage of `$locationprovider.html5mode(true)` is not working on page refreshing (not working on angular)

My `.htacess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My js in `core.config` in my core folder:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
```

Base Url:

```
<base href='<?php echo _WEBSITE_URL; ?>'>
```

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you have the following tag (in head) in your ``index.html`` - ``<base href="/" />``

Comment: @VladimirZdenek  Thank you for your quick response. I added the base url  **  <base href='<?php echo _WEBSITE_URL; ?>'>** but still its not working when i refresh the page